# Artefacts while ImplicitAnimation UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, win2d

I have an issue with my ImplicitAnimation. 
When the grid goes up, everything looks fine, but when the method CloseButton_Click is going and the grid goes down, artefacts like those in the image [Artefacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIXGe.png). Does anyone know how to fix it? I'll be grateful for every single idea.

My code looks like this:

```
public sealed partial class AddTaskView : UserControl
{
    private Compositor _compositor;
    private Visual myWindow;
    private Vector3KeyFrameAnimation offsetAnimation;
    private ImplicitAnimationCollection implicitAnimation;
    public AddTaskView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.InitializeTransition();
    }

    private void InitializeTransition()
    {
        WindowGrid.Height = ((Frame)Window.Current.Content).ActualHeight;
        WindowGrid.Width = ((Frame)Window.Current.Content).ActualWidth;
        myWindow = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(myWindowGrid);
        _compositor = myWindow.Compositor;
        myWindow.Size = new Vector2((float)((Frame)Window.Current.Content).ActualWidth
            , (float)((Frame)Window.Current.Content).ActualHeight);
    }

    private void ColorSlideTransitionCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myWindow.Size = new Vector2((float)((Frame)Window.Current.Content).ActualWidth
            , (float)((Frame)Window.Current.Content).ActualHeight);
        myWindow.Offset = new Vector3(0.0f, (float)WindowGrid.ActualHeight, 0.0f);
        offsetAnimation = _compositor.CreateVector3KeyFrameAnimation();
        offsetAnimation.Target = nameof(Visual.Offset);
        offsetAnimation.InsertExpressionKeyFrame(1.0f, "this.FinalValue");
        offsetAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000);


        implicitAnimation = _compositor.CreateImplicitAnimationCollection();
        implicitAnimation[nameof(Visual.Offset)] = offsetAnimation;
        myWindow.ImplicitAnimations = implicitAnimation;
        #region slide
        myWindow.Offset = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        #endregion
    }


    private void CloseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myWindow.Offset = new Vector3(0.0f, (float)((Frame)Window.Current.Content).ActualHeight, 0.0f);
    }
}
```

**OffTopic**: later, I want to connect this animation with a GaussianBlurEffect. Is it possible to do it? Do you have any tips for me? I'll be grateful too.

Comment: Can you create a sample project? Your code looks OK to me.

Comment: I don't know why but today my code works well... I've tried to find the reason why it didn't work yesterday, but I can't find any of them.. Sorry for bothering You. Can I ask you about connecting this animation with GaussianBlurEffect? Is there any other option to do it without using InteractionTracker? Thank you for your response.